# Scheme: Constant Access to the End of a List?

Tags: list, scheme, complexity-theory, racket

In C, you can have a pointer to the first and last element of a singly-linked list, providing constant time access to the end of a list. Thus, appending one list to another can be done in constant time.

As far as I am aware, scheme does not provide this functionality (namely constant access to the end of a list) by default. To be clear, I am not looking for "pointer" functionality. I understand that is non-idiomatic in scheme and (as I suppose) unnecessary.

Could someone either 1) demonstrate the ability to provide a way to append two lists in constant time or 2) assure me that this is already available by default in scheme or racket (e.g., tell me that `append` is in fact a constant operation if I am wrong to think otherwise)?

EDIT: 
I should make myself clearer. I am trying to create an inspectable queue. I want to have a list that I can 1) push onto the front in constant time, 2) pop off the back in constant time, and 3) iterate over using Racket's `foldr` or something similar (a Lisp right fold).

Comment: By the way: Racket already has a queue structure: http://docs.racket-lang.org/data/Imperative_Queues.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Standard Lisp lists cannot be appended to in constant time.

However, if you make your own list type, you can do it. Basically, you can use a record type (or just a cons cell)---let's call this the "header"---that holds pointers to the head and tail of the list, and update it each time someone adds to the list.

However, be aware that if you do that, lists are no longer structurally inductive. i.e., a longer list isn't simply an extension of a shorter list, because of the extra "header" involved. Thus, you lose a great part of the simplicity of Lisp algorithms which involve recursing into the `cdr` of a list at each iteration.

In other words, the lack of easy appending is a tradeoff to enable recursive algorithms to be written much more easily. Most functional programmers will agree that this is the right tradeoff, since appending in a pure-functional sense means that you have to copy every cell in all but the last list---so it's no longer O(1), anyway.

---

**ETA to reflect OP's edit**

You can create a queue, but with the opposite behaviour: you add elements to the back, and retrieve elements in the front. If you are willing to work with that, such a data structure is [easy to implement in Scheme](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/guile.git/tree/module/ice-9/q.scm). (And yes, it's easy to append two such queues in constant time.)

Racket also has a similar [queue data structure](http://docs.racket-lang.org/data/Imperative_Queues.html), but it uses a record type instead of cons cells, because Racket cons cells are immutable. You can convert your queue to a list using `queue->list` (at O(n) complexity) for times when you need to fold.

Comment: The "opposite behavior" comment is misleading; the behavior is exactly the same, the only difference is which ends the OP and you are metaphorically labeling as the "front" and the "back."

Answer (score 5):

You want a FIFO queue.  user448810 mentions the standard implementation for a purely-functional FIFO queue.

Your concern about losing the "key advantage of Lisp lists" needs to be unpacked a bit:

- You can write combinators for custom data structures in Lisp.  If you implement a queue type, you can easily write fold, map, filter and so on for it.
- Scheme, however, does lack in the area of providing polymorphic sequence functions that can work on multiple sequence types.  You do often end up either (a) converting your data structures back to lists in order to use the rich library of list functions, or (b) implementing your own versions of various of these functions for your custom types.
- This is very much a shame, because singly-linked lists, while they are hugely useful for tons of computations, are not a do-all data structure.
- But what is worse is that there's a lot of Lisp folk who like to pretend that lists are a "universal datatype" that can and should be used to represent any kind of data.  I've programmed Lisp for a living, and oh my god I hate the code that these people produce; I call it "Lisp programmer's disease," and have much too often had to go in and fix a lot of n^2 that uses lists to represent sets or dictionaries to use hash tables or search trees instead.  Don't fall into that trap.  Use proper data structures for the task at hand.  You can always build your own opaque data types using record types and modules in Racket; you make them opaque by exporting the type but not the field accessors for the record type (you export your type's user-facing operations instead).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are looking for a deque, not a list. The standard idiom for a deque is to keep two lists, the front half of the list in normal order and the back half of the list in reverse order, thus giving access to both ends of the deque. If the half of the list that you want to access is empty, reverse the other half and swap the meaning of the two halves. Look [here](http://programmingpraxis.com/2011/09/06/deques/) for a fuller explanation and sample code.

Comment: Even a queue (with a header cons cell that points to the head and tail) will do. But both approaches lose a key advantage of Lisp lists, as explained in my answer.